# F# in SublimeText 2

Tags: f#, sublimetext2

I'm having some trouble running this F# in SublimeText 2.

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "Hello World" 
    0
```

When I run it I get the error:

*Files in libraries or multiple-file applications must begin with a namespace or module declaration, e.g. 'namespace SomeNamespace.SubNamespace' or 'module SomeNamespace.SomeModule'*

The same code runs fine in Visual Studio

Comment: Have you tried adding a namespace as the message suggest?

Comment: I did, as per Mau's suggestion below and it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, your file should start with a module or namespace declaration (unless it's the last file passed to the compiler). It's common practice to include the `main` function in an aptly named module.
For example, put:

```
module Main
```

at the beginning of the file.
You can also pick another name of your choice.

Comment: thanks, that works. Would you know why I didn't need to do that in Visual Studio? Is VS doing something different?

Comment: Is SublimeText using the `fsc` compiler? What command line does it generate for the build? A single file or the last file in a set should be allowed to be 'anonymous' and VS normally respects that.

Comment: no, it's set up to use the repl, fsi.exe. Switching to fsc builds an executable rather than running it.

Comment: it actually compiles fine with out the `module main` when using the fsc compiler. I guess the thing that I was missing was that VS was compiling and then running